# GWT plugin for eclipse 4.3

Tags: eclipse, gwt, installation, google-eclipse-plugin, eclipse-kepler

I have the new version of eclipse: Eclipse Kepler 4.3.
I'm looking for GWT plugin for that version of eclipse but I can not find.
If I try to install the plugin for 4.2 eclipse version, what could happen?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything can happen ;-) . Kepler is still a release candidate of eclipse. Once eclipse releases it officially google gwt team will release the updated gwt plugin.

If you are just using it for GWT development then you can stick to juno instead of migrating to a RC candidate of kepler.

Answer (score 2):

The GWT plugin for kepler is ready -

See links below, please let me know if it works for you

**Website:** [4.3 update site](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3)

**URL:** https://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3

**Doc Link:** [4.3 docs](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the 4.2 GWT plugin with Kepler and it works fine. I've found Kepler a little buggy in places but that is to be expected, as it is not yet released.

Answer (score 1):

Good news - the kepler plugin is ready - I also waited for it.
I just upgraded my kepler from using 4.2 to 4.3 - looks OK

See links below, please let me know if it works for you

[4.3 update site](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/4.3)
[4.3 docs](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3)